# Safely retrieve values from element that can contain different values

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

We have some xml elements in a database that [for older data] can sometimes contain guids and sometimes contain integers.

is there a nice way of pulling out all the integrs only?

This will fail if the `value` element contains a guid!

```
select
ra.*,
t.c.value('.', 'int') as organisationId
from 
   Audit.EmployeeAudit ra
   cross apply ra.EmployeeXml.nodes('//*:employee/*:property[*:name="ORG"]/*:value') t(c)
```

**Sample Xml**

```
<employee>
  <property>
    <name>ORG</name>
    <value>39</value> <!-- Sometimes this will be a guid -->
    <description>Leeds</description>
  </property>
</employee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a predicate to only match entries of less than or equal to 10 characters.

```
;with EmployeeAudit as
(

SELECT CAST('<employee><property>
   <name>ORG</name>
   <value>39</value> <!-- Sometimes this will be a guid -->
   <description>Leeds</description>
</property></employee>
' AS XML) AS EmployeeXml
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('<employee><property>
   <name>ORG</name>
   <value>2FD29F11-59FC-47FD-BC30-DD330A53284E</value> 
   <description>Leeds</description>
</property></employee>
' AS XML)
)
select
ra.*,
t.c.value('.', 'int') as organisationId
from 
   EmployeeAudit ra
   cross apply 
   ra.EmployeeXml.nodes
   ('//*:employee/*:property[*:name="ORG"]/*:value[string-length() <= 10]') t(c)
```

Or actually this might be a bit more robust

```
('//*:employee/*:property[*:name="ORG"]/*:value[ceiling(.) = .]') t(c)
```

Comment: I'd actually thought of using the content length, It does work nicely.. excellent.

Comment: @Dog Ears - My first solution would still fail if you ever had text `ABC` as a value I've added an alternative.

Comment: Many thanks - All these functions coming to light have encouraged me to actually look for the 'docs' for this stuff and i've now found this..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189254.aspx very useful. Thanks. (+1 btw)

Comment: The docs say if something about, "Any other type generates a static error" what does that mean? could we just use number(.)=. would that work equally?